# Set priority when using Beyond Compare to solve conflicts after a merge

Tags: git, merge, beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I can see on the [Beyond Compare option list](http://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?command_line_reference.html) for the mergetool that one can specify to favor the right or the left side with `-favorright` or `-favorleft` option.

If I try to use it I get an error

```
$git merge master

[...](Actual merge with some conflicts)

$git mergetool -favorright
usage: git mergetool [--tool=tool] [--tool-help] [-y|--no-prompt|--prompt] [-O<orderfile>] [file to merge] ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `-favorright` argument to `git`. What you want is for `git` to pass that argument to Beyond Compare. This command will change your configuration for every future use of `git mergetool`.

```
$ git config --global mergetool.bc3.cmd "/usr/bin/bcompare -favorright \$LOCAL
\$REMOTE \$BASE \$MERGED"
```

You may need to substitute `/usr/bin/bcompare` for the correct path to the Beyond Compare executable on your system.